# Onvif unicast probe message

Tags: c++, gsoap, onvif, ws-discovery

I want to test my software with onvif device test tool (version 16.07 SR1), I am managed to reply multicast probe messages, I am tring to confirm that my software works with device discovery completely but when test tool sends unicast probe messages, my software responds same as multicast probe messages, and  it gives an error "Unexpected error occured. There is an error in XML document (0,0)." and my tests fails. I checked messages using wireshark, I am definitely sending same message with my multicast probe respond. Is there any difference between unicast and multicast probe matches messages?

multicast probe :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Envelope xmlns:tds="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><Header><wsa:MessageID xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">uuid:c6023c78-864b-4a48-a901-bebcf1088730</wsa:MessageID><wsa:To xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">urn:schemas-xmlsoap-org:ws:2005:04:discovery</wsa:To><wsa:Action xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/Probe</wsa:Action></Header><Body><Probe xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery"><Types>tds:Device</Types><Scopes /></Probe></Body></Envelope><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Envelope xmlns:dn="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/network/wsdl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><Header><wsa:MessageID xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">uuid:e4b0668d-39af-44ea-b1a4-e2322d88668e</wsa:MessageID><wsa:To xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">urn:schemas-xmlsoap-org:ws:2005:04:discovery</wsa:To><wsa:Action xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/Probe</wsa:Action></Header><Body><Probe xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery"><Types>dn:NetworkVideoTransmitter</Types><Scopes /></Probe></Body></Envelope><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Envelope xmlns:tds="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><Header><wsa:MessageID xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">uuid:c6023c78-864b-4a48-a901-bebcf1088730</wsa:MessageID><wsa:To xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">urn:schemas-xmlsoap-org:ws:2005:04:discovery</wsa:To><wsa:Action xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/Probe</wsa:Action></Header><Body><Probe xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery"><Types>tds:Device</Types><Scopes /></Probe></Body></Envelope><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Envelope xmlns:dn="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/network/wsdl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><Header><wsa:MessageID xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">uuid:e4b0668d-39af-44ea-b1a4-e2322d88668e</wsa:MessageID><wsa:To xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">urn:schemas-xmlsoap-org:ws:2005:04:discovery</wsa:To><wsa:Action xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/Probe</wsa:Action></Header><Body><Probe xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery"><Types>dn:NetworkVideoTransmitter</Types><Scopes /></Probe></Body></Envelope>
```

multicast probe match (after this reply, my device showed in list of discovered devices) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:saml1="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:sizexenc="http://tempuri.org/sizexenc.xsd" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:sizeds="http://tempuri.org/sizeds.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:wsc="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:chan="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/02/duplex" xmlns:wsa5="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsdd="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery" xmlns:xmime="http://tempuri.org/xmime.xsd" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" xmlns:tt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema" xmlns:wsnt="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2" xmlns:wsrfbf="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2" xmlns:wstop="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1" xmlns:tdn="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/network/wsdl" xmlns:tds="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl" xmlns:tptz="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl" xmlns:trt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl"><SOAP-ENV:Header><wsa5:MessageID>urn:uuid:119d6358-a7a0-41e4-b167-f00199b0625d</wsa5:MessageID><wsa5:RelatesTo>uuid:c6023c78-864b-4a48-a901-bebcf1088730</wsa5:RelatesTo><wsa5:To SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa5:To><wsa5:Action SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/ProbeMatches</wsa5:Action><wsdd:AppSequence InstanceId="0" MessageNumber="6"></wsdd:AppSequence></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><wsdd:ProbeMatches><wsdd:ProbeMatch><wsa5:EndpointReference><wsa5:Address>http://10.0.0.50:1881/</wsa5:Address></wsa5:EndpointReference><wsdd:Types>tdn:NetworkVideoTransmitter tds:Device</wsdd:Types><wsdd:Scopes>onvif://www.onvif.org/name/Company onvif://www.onvif.org/hardware/Imx onvif://www.onvif.org/Profile/Streaming onvif://www.onvif.org/location/Any onvif://www.onvif.org/type/NetworkVideoTransmitter onvif://www.onvif.org/type/video_encoder onvif://www.onvif.org/type/audio_encoder onvif://www.onvif.org/type/ptz </wsdd:Scopes><wsdd:XAddrs>http://10.0.0.50:1881/</wsdd:XAddrs><wsdd:MetadataVersion>1</wsdd:MetadataVersion></wsdd:ProbeMatch></wsdd:ProbeMatches></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

unicast probe:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Envelope xmlns:dn="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/network/wsdl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><Header><wsa:MessageID xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">uuid:289ceb4f-5b1a-420f-bae4-5a8e1f918436</wsa:MessageID><wsa:To xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">urn:schemas-xmlsoap-org:ws:2005:04:discovery</wsa:To><wsa:Action xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/Probe</wsa:Action></Header><Body><Probe xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery"><Types>dn:NetworkVideoTransmitter</Types><Scopes /></Probe></Body></Envelope><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

unicast probematch reply (after this message Onvif Device Test Tool gives error above):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:saml1="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:sizexenc="http://tempuri.org/sizexenc.xsd" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:sizeds="http://tempuri.org/sizeds.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:wsc="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:chan="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/02/duplex" xmlns:wsa5="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsdd="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery" xmlns:xmime="http://tempuri.org/xmime.xsd" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" xmlns:tt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema" xmlns:wsnt="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2" xmlns:wsrfbf="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2" xmlns:wstop="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1" xmlns:tdn="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/network/wsdl" xmlns:tds="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl" xmlns:tptz="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl" xmlns:trt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl"><SOAP-ENV:Header><wsa5:MessageID>urn:uuid:b3f100d9-1453-49da-8352-8dbd011a884d</wsa5:MessageID><wsa5:RelatesTo>uuid:289ceb4f-5b1a-420f-bae4-5a8e1f918436</wsa5:RelatesTo><wsa5:To SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa5:To><wsa5:Action SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/ProbeMatches</wsa5:Action><wsdd:AppSequence InstanceId="0" MessageNumber="2"></wsdd:AppSequence></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><wsdd:ProbeMatches><wsdd:ProbeMatch><wsa5:EndpointReference><wsa5:Address>http://10.0.0.50:1881/</wsa5:Address></wsa5:EndpointReference><wsdd:Types>tdn:NetworkVideoTransmitter tds:Device</wsdd:Types><wsdd:Scopes>onvif://www.onvif.org/name/Company onvif://www.onvif.org/hardware/Imx onvif://www.onvif.org/Profile/Streaming onvif://www.onvif.org/location/Any onvif://www.onvif.org/type/NetworkVideoTransmitter onvif://www.onvif.org/type/video_encoder onvif://www.onvif.org/type/audio_encoder onvif://www.onvif.org/type/ptz </wsdd:Scopes><wsdd:XAddrs>http://10.0.0.50:1881/</wsdd:XAddrs><wsdd:MetadataVersion>1</wsdd:MetadataVersion></wsdd:ProbeMatch></wsdd:ProbeMatches></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: can you somehow put a dump here of the packets?

Comment: I put xml messages from packets

Comment: @OttavioCampana

Comment: @rotringuser At first look the only remarkable difference between mentioned probematch packets are encoding value at the beginning of the xml. in unicast probematch change encoding="utf-8" to encoding="UTF-8". might look dumb but if i were you i would give it a try :)!